# Azure API Management Policy to JSON Encode an Inbound Header Value

Tags: json, xml, azure, azure-api-management

I have an API that requires a header that accepts a JSON value.

Example:
`curl --location 'https://someapi/foo' --header 'header-name: {"x":[{"a":"100","b":"200"}]}'`

When sending the request from postman, it works fine.  However, when my vendor attempts to call the API it fails.  When I log the header, it is coming over as
`{&quot;x&quot;:[{&quot;a&quot;:&quot;100&quot;,&quot;b&quot;:&quot;200&quot;}]}`

Can I use an inbound policy in Azure APIM to properly encode this header?

Answer (score 0):

As you right pointed it out, APIM can be used to achieve this ask via inbound policy. The incoming request headers format should be `html decoded` before sending it to the backend API endpoint.

Below is an example, Please update it as per your requirement:

```
<inbound>
  <base />
  <set-header name="header-name" exists-action="override">
    <value>@(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(context.Request.Headers["header-name"].ToString()))</value>
  </set-header>
</inbound>
```

More Info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-header-policy) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies#advanced-policies). Hope this helps.